# What should the following code do and with explanations

Tags: c++

```
class A { 
 public:
  A() { } 
  ~A() { cout << "A Destructor \n" ; } 
};

class B :public A{ 
   public:
   B() { } 
   virtual ~B() { cout << "B Destructor \n" ; } 
};

class C : public B {
   public:
   C() { }
   ~C() { cout << "C Destructor \n"; }
};

int main()
{

   A *pointA = new A;
   A *pointB = new B;
   A *pointC = new C;

   delete pointA;
   delete pointB;
   delete pointC;
}
```

Comment: Gotta agree with Patrick, smells like homework.

Comment: It is not homework. I'm trying to understand, why it throws undefined behaviour?

Comment: @nsivakr: If you know the code results in undefined behavior and you wonder why, make that part of your question. Always try to make your questions as specific as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will invoke undefined behavior at the second (and third) delete, because A's destructor is not virtual.

§5.3.5/3:

> if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the
>   static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

---

If you make the destructor of A virtual, you get well-defined behavior, and the destructor of the dynamic type is called. (And each of those in turn calls the base destructor.) Your output would be:

> A destructor
>   B destructor
>   A destructor
>   C destructor
>   B destructor
>   A destructor

---

For what it's worth, when you're that close to a compilable snippet, you should leave the includes. Also, just use `struct` instead of `class` to be concise about the `public` stuff, and leave out empty constructors.

Answer (score 0):

As GMan pointed out, attempting to call the delete operator on a base pointer requires a virtual destructor for the compiler to be able to destroy subclass objects correctly. A lot of people oversimplify this to a rule like, "If a class has virtual functions, it needs a virtual destructor." That is not necessarily the case; even a base class which has no virtual functions still needs a virtual destructor if you want to allow clients to delete the class through a base pointer. If you don't, the destructor should be protected and not public.

There is an excellent book that describes this in detail and more called C++ Coding Standards by Herb Sutter. I recommend it as a starting point in your C++ adventures. :-)